# How to implement a doGenerate-method?

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, xtend

i want to implement a doGenerate method. I dont understand how I should develop all these methods. Maybe someone can give me an example for the first 2-3 methods for my issue.

Thats my Xtext-file:

```
Model:
    usestory += UseStory*;

UseStory:
title=Title role=Role target=Target use=Use;


Title:   
    titlen= NOUN  titlev=Verbwrapper ':';

Role:
    'Als' role=NOUN;

Target:
    'möchte' 'ich' targetn=NOUN targetv=Verbwrapper ',';

Use:
   'um' usen=NOUN 'zu' usev=Verbwrapper '.';


Verbwrapper: value=VERB;



terminal NOUN: ('Ä'|'Ö'|'Ü'|('A'..'Z'))(('a'..'z')|'ä'|'ö'|'ü'|'ß')*;
terminal VERB: ('ä'|'ö'|'ü'|'ß'|('a'..'z'))+('en')|('eln')|('n');
```

And that is what I read about Xtend, can not understand the implementation of the single methods.

```
/*
 * generated by Xtext 2.19.0
 */
class HellodslGenerator extends AbstractGenerator{

    String code

    override void doGenerate
(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa,IGeneratorContext context)
{
    code=""
for (e: resource.allContents.filter(Model).toIterable)
{
    e.funktion
}
fsa.generateFile("test.txt",code)
}


def conc(String str) { 
code = code + str;
}

def funktion(Model m)
    m.UseStory.funktion

}
```

I want to print simply all the sentences which stand in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

you usually dont generate based on what is in the editor, but rather on what is in the AST. you also usually use the rich string feature from Xtend if you write a generator in Xtend. this could very simplyfied look like

```
class MyDslGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {

    override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
        fsa.generateFile("test.txt", '''
        «FOR model : resource.allContents.filter(Model).toIterable»
            «FOR userStory : model.usestory»
            userstory
            - title: «userStory.title.titlen» «userStory.title.titlev.value»
            - role: «userStory.role»
            - target: «userStory.target.targetn» «userStory.target.targetv.value»
            - use: «userStory.use.usen» «userStory.use.usev.value»
            «ENDFOR»
        «ENDFOR»
        ''')
    }
}
```

of course you can also access the text via the nodemodel.
this would look something like

```
class MyDslGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {

    override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
        fsa.generateFile("test.txt", '''
        «FOR model : resource.allContents.filter(Model).toIterable»
            «FOR userStory : model.usestory»
                «NodeModelUtils.findActualNodeFor(userStory)»
            «ENDFOR»
        «ENDFOR»
        ''')
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I access the values in this example?
`grammar htmlprojekt.Htmlprojekt with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate htmlprojekt "http://www.Htmlprojekt.htmlprojekt"

Model:
 ('<table>'  tabelle += Tabelle '</table>')*
;

Tabelle:
  {Tabelle} zeile+=Zeile*;

Zeile:
 (spalte+=Spalte)+;

Spalte:
 '<tr>' (spalteninhalt+=Spalteninhalt)+ '</tr>'
;

Spalteninhalt:
 {Spalteninhalt} '<td>' (textinhalt+=Textinhalt)* '</td>'
;

Textinhalt:
 text=ID
;`

Is it possible or do I have to change something?

Comment: simply iterate over model.tabelle?

Comment: Do I have to implement a value-method here? If yes how?

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you are talking about. what is a value method maybe you can ask a new question what your input is, what your desired output is, what you currently do in the generator

Comment: I want to write all what stands in the xtext editor in a .txt file. I dont know how to access my values. It is a other structure as in my first example on the upper side.

Other question: Is it possible to do something like this: 
`terminal x: ('0'...'9'){3};`
 in xtext?

Or is it not possible to delimit the number of characters?

Comment: and NodeModelUtils does not work? i dont think you can do the 3 thing